# Need to make a set of graphs in excel using a vba macro loop

Tags: excel, vba, loops, graph

I'm trying to make a macro that will run through an excel sheet and go through a set of rows and make a graph for each row.

I've got a bit of code that kind of does what I need, but puts it all on one graph when I need an individual graph for each row.

```
`Dim i As Integer
 Dim ws As Worksheet
 Set ws = Sheets("Master Sheet")
 For Row = 1 To 20
 Dim my_cell
 Dim rng As Range
 Set rng = Sheets("Master Sheet").Range("J8:Y8")

 For Each my_cell In rng
 If my_cell <> "" Then

 ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
 ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("'Master Sheet'!$J$8:$Y$8")
 ActiveChart.ChartType = xlLineMarkers
 ActiveChart.Location Where:=xlLocationAsNewSheet
 ActiveSheet.Activate
 ActiveChart.PlotArea.Select
 ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = "='Master Sheet'!$J$2:$Y$2"
 ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Name = "=""FP"""
 ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
 ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).Name = "=""Progress"""
 ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).Values = _
 "='Master Sheet'!$J$8,'Master Sheet'!$AF$8:$AH$8"
 ActiveChart.DisplayBlanksAs = xlInterpolated
 ActiveSheet.Activate
 ActiveChart.ChartArea.Select

 Else
 Exit For ' Blank cell found, exiting
 End If
 Next

 Next Row
 End Sub`
```

If anyone can give me a hand to see where I'm going wrong that would be great.

Answer (score 2):

Not really sure you have structured your `For Next` and `For Each` loops well. Ideally you'd like to step through ranges and actually use the value you define in your `For Each` statement. Without seeing your workbook I just adapted a small range of data to simulate creating a graph.

I just took your same code and generate a graph on the same worksheet for each row of numbers. You can take these principles and apply it to your logic.

```
Sub test()
 Dim Row As Integer
 Dim ws As Worksheet
 Dim rng As Range

 Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1") 'Change this to: Set ws = Sheets("Master Sheet")

 For Row = 1 To 6
 Set rng = ws.Range("B1:D1").Offset(Row, 0) 'Change to (I'm guessing here): ws.Range("$J$7:$Y$7").Offset(Row, 0)

 ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
 ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range(ws.Name & "!" & rng.Address)
 ActiveChart.ChartType = xlLineMarkers
 ActiveChart.PlotArea.Select
 ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = "='Sheet1'!$B$1:$D$1" 'Change to "='Master Sheet'!$J$2:$Y$2"
 ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Name = ws.Range("A1").Offset(Row, 0).Value 'Change this to whatever you want to name the graphs. This is currently set to dynamicly name each graph by the series name set in Column A.
 'ActiveChart.Location Where:=xlLocationAsNewSheet 'uncomment this line to put on new sheet
 'ws.Select 'Need to go back to worksheet

 Next Row

 Set ws = nothing
 Set rng = nothing
End Sub
```

Here are a couple links that may help;
[Creating and positioning graphs in a for loop VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11415063/creating-and-positioning-graphs-in-a-for-loop-vba) and 
[Excel VBA: Chart-making macro that will loop through unique name groups and create corresponding charts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12685660/excel-vba-chart-making-macro-that-will-loop-through-unique-name-groups-and-crea)

Google also has many other links.

If I've misunderstood your question or need anything else please let me know.

Cheers

Comment: Thanks for the help, I've given you code a try and I'm getting an error with this line 

    `ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range(ws.Name & "!" & rng.Address)`

I'm not sure why, but as it's late it could be me just not seeing it. I think I'll sleep on it and have a look in the morning.

Thanks again for the help.

Comment: Have you changed `Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")` to your sheet name `Set ws = Sheets("Master Sheet")`. Sorry I should have done that in the code, but all the range references will need to be changed as well.